# VB Scripting error.. Object Required

Tags: vbscript

This is my first day with VB scripting. I found following code to search and replace text in a text file  but when I run that using the following command

`cscript replace.vbs "test.txt" "Jim" "James"`

I get an error saying

`replace.vbs(6, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required: 'Scripting'`

Here is the code

```
Const ForReading = 1    
Const ForWriting = 2
strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)
Set objFSO = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewText  'WriteLine adds extra CRLF
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

(mark the quotes, CreateObject() needs a string)